# How do you implement the trait TypeInfo for H256?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits, rust-cargo, substrate

Compilation gives this error:

error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256`

[image]

I tried implement derive TypeInfo in Primitives/core/src/hasher.rs, but this did not work.

[image]

How do I solve this error please?

GitHub Repo: Can supply if required...

rustup show:

[image]

Command used: cargo build --release

cargo tree -d output: Can supply if required...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

The crate primitive-types provide the feature `scale-info`, when compiled with this feature the crate will implement `TypeInfo` on the primitive types such as H256

Comment: I got similar problems: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/trait-bound-h256-typeinfo-is-not-satisfiedthe-typeinfo-is-not-implemented

Comment: Thank you, this comment is helpful.